# Why does filtering output of git diff with findstr using a regular expression to get just lines ending with .js not work?

Tags: git, cmd, findstr, pre-commit-hook

I'm working on my first JavaScript project. Someone advised me to use ESLint with a GIT pre-hook to often check my code. I'm writing my own pre-hook to pass to ESLint (only the changed files will be checked). I'm trying to find every file with the .js extension. I tried the following solutions but none is working:

```
git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM | findstr /R  ".js$"  => Returns nothing
git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM | findstr /R  ".js"   => Returns .JS and .JSON
git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM | findstr /R  ".js^$" => Returns nothing
```

Could someone help me with the regular expression to find every file with the .js extension?

Comment: `".js$"` should work. You might add a `/i` to make it cases insensible and replace `.` (which means "any character") to `\.` (exactly a dot). You could also use the `/e` parameter instead of using `$` `... findstr /r /e "\.js"`. If not: are you sure, the returned string doesn't have a space at the end?

Comment: This is not working, I'm not sure if git diff at spaces at the end, but that doesn't makes sense in my opinion. How should I handle spaces at the end?

Comment: first check, if there are spaces, before you think how to handle them: On command line type: `for /f "delims=" %a in ('git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter^=ACM') do @echo --%a--` and check the output.

Answer (score 1):

Open a command prompt window and run `findstr /?` to get output the help of this standard Windows console application.

There is perhaps no need for a regular expression find at all. A simple *case-insensitive* (`/I`) interpreted *literal* (`/L`) search string with the additional option to match only lines *ending* (`/E`) with that string is enough.

```
git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM | findstr /E /I /L .js
```

Another solution is using `/C:` which results in interpreting the search string by default also as literal string (in most cases) except option `/R` is also used forcing *regular* expression interpretation.

```
git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM | findstr /E /I /C:.js
```

But in case of the lines output by `git` have trailing spaces or horizontal tabs it is really necessary to use a case-insensitive regular expression find.

```
git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM | findstr /I /R /C:"\.js[    ]*$"
```

`.` must be escaped with a backslash in search expression to be interpreted as literal character instead of its regular expression meaning of any character.

Please note that one character in square bracket is a space character and the other one is a horizontal tab character. The tab character is displayed above and below according to HTML standard as a sequence of 1 or more spaces.

In this case better use a batch file as it is really difficult to "type" a tab character in a command prompt window.

```
git.exe diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R /C:"\.js[  ]*$"
```

It is advisable in a batch file to specify files/scripts to execute with file extension and if possible also with full path to make the batch file independent on current values of the environment variables `PATH` and `PATHEXT` as much as possible.

Comment: `echo foobar.xjs|findstr /E /I .js` ... `findstr` is doing REGEX even without `/R`.

Comment: @Mofi Both of your solutions return 0 files, while I have 2 files which ends with .js

Comment: @CorneElshof That's not the fault of __FINDSTR__. I suggest to run in a command prompt window `git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM >"%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\GitDiffOutput.txt"`. If you see text output into command prompt window, `git` outputs the text to handle __STDERR__ instead of __STDOUT__. Open text file `GitDiffOutput.txt` on your desktop. Does it contain lines ending with `.js` with no trailing spaces/tabs? Which encoding is used, ANSI or Unicode? Which line termination is used, carriage return + line-feed (DOS/Windows) or just line-feed (UNIX)?